# Data points do not display when specifying axis in R

Tags: r, graph

For some reason if I try to display data with the following code, I get the axis right, but the actual data does not plot. Any suggestions?

```
par(bg="lightgray")
adates <-as.Date(row.names(try),format="%Y-%m-%d")
plot(try[,1],x=adates,type="o",axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
usr <- par("usr")
rect(usr[1], usr[3], usr[2], usr[4], col="cornsilk", border="black")
lines(try[,1], col="blue")

axis(2,col.axis="blue",,at=pretty(try[,1]),las=1,labels=sprintf("$%1.0f",pretty(try[,1]/1000)),cex.axis=.75)

axis.Date(1, at=pretty(adates), label=format(pretty(adates),"%y"))
box()
title(main="This is a graph", font.main=4, col.main="red",xlab="Date",ylab="$ (in $1000s)")
```

Comment: show an example of your data, 'try'.

Comment: ...and don't call your data `try`, since that's a function for dealing with errors.

Comment: You do realize that dates are numeric values expressed in days offset from 1970, right?

Comment: Maybe consider rethinking the colour scheme too, if you are going to make anyone else look at the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgetting all the other bits of code, take a look at

```
plot(try[,1],x=adates,type="o",axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
```

The first argument to plot is the vector x-coordinates, which in this case is `try[,1]`.  You then provide another set of x-coordinates with `x=adates`.  So now you have two sets of x-coords but no y-coords.